# On Linear Independence of a Set

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a problem about linear independence of sets.

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Suppose
that $n$ and $k$ are positive integers.

(i) If $w\in V$ s.t. $T^k(w)\neq0$ and $T^{k+1}(w)=0$, must $\{w, T(w),...,T^k(w)\}$ linearly independent?

(ii) Let $W$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by $\{w, T(w),...,T^k(w)\}$ as in part (i). If $v\in V$ s.t. $T^n(v)\notin W$ and $T^{n+1}(v)\in W$ must $\{w, T(w),...,T^k(w),v,T(v),\ldots,T^n(v)\}$ be
linearly independent?

Based on definition of linear independent set and the assumption of the problem in both parts, I think in both parts the sets are L.I. 
That is kind of you friends to help in answering this problem.

Comment: It'd be kind of you if you show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Javi What I tried is that, since $T^{k+1}(w)=0$ then for scalars $c_1,\ldots, c_k$, the expression $c_1w+c_2T(w)+\ldots + c_kT^k(w)=0$ implies that $c_1=\ldots=c_k=0$ implying that the set is L.I. Similar argument for part (ii). But, I guess my argument is not fine.

Comment: Have you considered what happens if $T$ is the identity map?

Comment: @GregMartin Do you mean $T(w)=w$? I have not tried but if so, we have for some values $T(w)=0$ which is not identity. Actually I am not a math student, this problem looks hard to me.

Comment: The implication is right, but you should write it in more detail, i.e., the coefficients are 0 because $T^k(c_1w+c_2T(w)+\cdots +c_kTk(w))=c_1T^k(w)+c_2T^{k+1}(w)+\cdots +c_kT^{2k-1}=c_1T^k(w)=0$, which implies $c_1=0$. Then you do the same applying $T^{k-1}$ and so on.

Comment: @Javi Thank you so much for your help. You are right and your argument is fine. How about second part? Since $T^n(v)$ is not in $W$ that confuses me. Should I do the same as part i for scalars $c_1,...,c_k,d_1,...,d_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part(i) can be proved similarly by induction, so I'll just assume part(i) holds. Then part(ii) is equivalent to:

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$, $v\in V $ but $v\notin W$. If $n+1$ is the first index such that $T^{n+1}(v)\in W$, then $span\{T^{0}(v),\ldots,T^{n}(v)\}\cap W=\{0\}$.

Put differently, we can prove $\forall m \in \{ 0,1,\ldots,n\}$, $span\{T^{n-m}(v),\ldots,T^{n}(v)\}\cap W=\{0\}$. Note that due to part(i) $\{T^{n-m}(v),\ldots,T^{n}(v)\}$ are L.I., and W is invariant under T, which means $\forall w \in W, T(w) \in W$. If you express $w$ with basis and apply $T$ to it you'll easily see it.

Induction on $m$:

$m=0$ holds since $T^n(v) \notin W$.

$m\rightarrow m+1$:

Suppose $\exists a_{n-m},\ldots,a_{n}$ such that $\sum_{i=n-m}^{n}a_i T^i(v)\in W$, then we have $T(\sum_{i=n-m}^{n}a_i T^i(v))=\sum_{i=n-m+1}^{n}a_{i-1} T^i(v) \in W$ since $T^{n+1}(v)\in W$.

By induction hypothesis, $a_{n-m},\ldots, a_{n-1}$ are all zero.

Since $T^n(v)$ is nonzero, we can conclude $span\{T^{n-m}(v),\ldots,T^{n}(v)\}\cap W=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I understood to the large extent but I have a question: how does $span\{T^{n-m}(v),...,T^{n-m}(v)\}\cap V=\{0\}$ lead to the conclusion that the set is L.I. as we already know based on part (i) that this set must be L.I..

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, it should be W. Is that clear now?

Comment: Thank you very much, now that makes more sense now, however, my question is still there that how does $span\{T^{n-m}(v),..,T^n(v)\}\cap W=\{0\}$ helps us to reach the conclusion that the set is L.I.?

Comment: OK, let me put it this way. If a set is L.I., it can be viewed as a basis to span some subspace. The other way around is also true. If two sets U V's intersection is {0}, their basis combine to form the basis for U+V, hence they are L.I.

Comment: Got it now thanks a lot. I have another question which is that why $\sum_{i=n-m+1}^{n}a_{i-1}T^i(v)\in W$ while this sum includes $T^n(v) \notin W$?

Comment: That's is because W is invariant with respect to T. Sorry I have taken that for granted... You can check it if you express $w\in W$ with basis.